# Android Opengl loading new bitmap object in game cycle, is it a good idea?

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, game-engine

I am new to opengl i have just learnt to load bitmap using VBO technique. i am

**(1)Whether i should create new bitmap object in each cycle of game loop**

or

**(2)i should create all the bitmap object once at the starting of game and use them through-out the game?**

i have been using the 2nd option for canvas technique because loading lot of bitmaps is a bulky task so i don't include in the cylce. But opengl works in different way so i need suggestion on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely do not load stuff at each game cycle, if you need to change data from a vbo, do that only exacly when you need using glBufferSubData. Also hint opengl about the nature of the data using GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @PedroSassenVeiga i was expecting for same now my doubts are clear.